# previewing my posts on static page?

Tags: posts, query-posts

I am new to WP.

**What i allready have -**

I am building  a news blog with few posts categories. each category function as a different section (Economics, Sports etc.)

**What i want to  achieve-**

What i am trying to achieve is to set a static page that will preview the last post from each category and will serve as the main page of the "news site".

1. how can i nest posts preview on a static page (I understand that static pages are posts right?).
2. is there a way to retrieve all the posts from a specific date?
3. is there a way to group them by category?

I know it is a "Big" question. I am only looking for directions and not tutorial.

Thanks a lot

Shani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set a Static Page as your front page, create and assign a PHP Template for that page, and stack multiple Queries in the template to search out your required categories and display them. Here is one, you might have many:

```
// get the last post (any date) from 'Featured' category
$featured = new WP_Query( 'category_name=Featured&posts_per_page=1' );
if ( $featured->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $featured->have_posts() )
    {
        $featured->the_post(); // fill $post with data
        ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <!-- output markup and display the post(s) -->
            </div>
        <?php 
    }
}
rewind_posts();

// start next query
```

That should give you an idea, at least, there is a fair bit to it.  Good luck.